# How to import external links in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento

I import my products with MAGMI. In the description field, I imported a external link : `<(with no space)a href="http://xxxxxxx.xx" target="_blank>Linkname<(with no space)/a>`

On my first Magento 1.9 installation everything was working perfect. But now I have a curious problem.

In the description (html sight) the link is insert perfect. If I click on the link in front end I get something like this:

```
mymagentobaseurl.de/"http://xxxxxxx.xx"
```

I can't remember what I have done different to my first Magento installation.
The CSV is the same, the MAGMI settings are the same.

Have somebody a hint or a solution for me ?

br from germany,
Heiko

Comment: Hi, it seems to be a problem with the [ target="_blank" ]. If I edited this direkt in Magento, it works. I saved my CSV as UTF-8. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It was a Excel issue ! I think I use LibreOffice in furture.

Can be closed !